# How to install Cordova in Linux?

Tags: android, cordova

I have tried to install cordova in Linux several times. When installing I got a Error "java home not set" and then node related error.
Is there any step by step guide to install cordova?

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO INSTALL CORDOVA**

1. Install Java Development Kit (JDK) Eg:
   yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.79-2.5.5.1.59.amzn1.x86_64
2. Download and Install Android SDK.
   download the appropriate Eclipse/Android SDK package from the Android site. Extract the downloaded files to a location where you can leave them permanently.
   We now need to add this location to the PATH.

On Linux -

> $ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/adt-linux/sdk/platform-tools:/opt/java/adt-linux/sdk/tools
>   $ echo $PATH

On WIndows -

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\adt-windows\sdk\tools;C:\adt- windows\sdk\platform-tools"

::Exit command prompt and reopen for setx to take effect

> path

3. Install Android Build Tools - API 19
4. Install Apache Ant
   On Linux

   > sudo yum install ant

Ant should automatically be added to the PATH.

On Windows
Download Ant from Apache Website
Since Ant is not automatically added to the PATH, run the following:

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin"
>   ::Exit command prompt and reopen for setx to take effect
>   path

5. Install Node Package Manager
   On Linux

   > sudo yum install npm

On Windows, download the appropriate setup file from the NodeJS site and run it.

6. Install Cordova

   > npm install –g cordova
7. Set up Android Virtual Device

Answer (score 0):

**ERRORS ENCOUNTERED**

**JAVA_HOME Not Set**

On Linux

```
$ alternatives --config java
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> [Important. Don't Press Any  Other Key.]

Copy the Location under Command
eg. Location is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20.x86_64/

```
$ export JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20.x86_64/
```

**32bit Library Missing on Linux**

```
$ sudo yum install ia32-libs
```

**Link NodeJS and Node Folders on Linux**

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

[ ensure there are no trailing “/” (slash) after the nodejs or node ]